# Cancan: Ability class to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have Rails 3 application with Cancan 1.6.9 for authorization. I want to convert Ability class to JSON. Here is the my Ability class.

```
# encoding: utf-8

module Ability

  def self.for(guest)
    guest ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if guest.admin?
      AdminAbility.new(guest)
    elsif guest.assurer?
      AssurerAbility.new(guest)
    end
  end

  ##
  # Assurer
  class AssurerAbility
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      cannot :manage, User
      can :read, ExchangeRate
    end
  end

  ##
  # Admin
  class AdminAbility
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      can :manage, User
      can :manage, ExchangeRate
    end

  end

end
```

When I run `Ability.for(User.last).to_json` I get following errors:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError: object references itself
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:75:in `check_for_circular_references'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `block in encode_json'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `map'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `encode_json'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:48:in `block in encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:77:in `check_for_circular_references'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `block in encode_json'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `map'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `encode_json'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:48:in `block in encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:77:in `check_for_circular_references'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
... 19 levels...
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `block in encode_json'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `map'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `encode_json'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:48:in `block in encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:77:in `check_for_circular_references'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:31:in `encode'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails-3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:16:in `to_json'
    enter code here
```

And when I run `Ability.for(User.last).as_json` I get result. But it's not valid JSON result.

```
{"rules"=>[#<CanCan::Rule:0xaf5e81c @match_all=false, @base_behavior=false, @actions=[:manage], @subjects=[User(id: integer, password_digest: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, uic: string, role: string, name: string, register_no: string)], @conditions={}, @block=nil>, #<CanCan::Rule:0xaf5e72c @match_all=false, @base_behavior=true, @actions=[:read], @subjects=[ExchangeRate(id: integer, data: float, date: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)], @conditions={}, @block=nil>]}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Implement `self.as_json` method in your models and explicitly specify which fields to convert to JSON. After this you will be able to run `Ability.for(User.last).to_json` without errors.

---

Complete explanation: let's look at the structure of `Ability` as seen from [source](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/ability.rb):

- `Ability` instance has a field named `@rules`.
- Each rule has a field named `@subject` which is a flattened ActiveRecord class (`User`, `ExchangeRate` etc). Yes, *class*, not class instance.
- `@subject` gets converted to JSON and `CircularReferenceError` appears. Why?

The problem is, converting `User` or `ExchangeRate` class to JSON is not a good idea because their structure may be very complicated. For instance, if you try running `User.as_json`, the result might be like [this](http://pastebin.com/RLpVfb6y). Probably one of `User`'s fields references back to `User` and you get `CircularReferenceError`. To avoid this, specify which fields should be included into JSON representation of `User` (the same is applied for `ExchangeRate`):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  def self.as_json(options = {})
    { "class" => "User" }
  end
end
```